# How to check if a datagridview cell is empty through button click in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need help when filtering or checking if either one or more datagridview cell is null or not before saving the data. I have tried several codes but there is always an error. Below is the picture.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView1.Rows
    For i As Integer = 0 To rw.Cells.Count - 1                  
        If rw.Cells(i).Value Is Nothing OrElse rw.Cells(i).Value = DBNull.Value OrElse  String.IsNullOrWhitespace(rw.Cells(i).Value.ToString()) Then
                  'empty
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: ...Sir could you please translate it vb.net code please..Thanks

Comment: Translated to vb. I hope it helps

Comment: Sir I have tried your suggested codes but it still saves although there are empty cells

Comment: Sir I have found the solution. I just replaced 'String.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.Cells(i).Value)' to 'String.IsNullOrWhitespace(rw.Cells(i).Value.ToString())'. Anyway thanks a lot for the idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function like this :

```
Public Function IsDataGridViewEmpty(ByRef dataGridView As DataGridView) As Boolean
    Dim isEmpty As Boolean = True
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Trim(cell.Value.ToString())) Then
                    isEmpty = False
                    Exit For
                End If
             End If
        Next
    Next
    Return isEmpty
 End Function
```

or with Linq :

```
Public Function IsDataGridViewEmpty(ByRef dataGridView As DataGridView) As Boolean
    Dim isEmpty As Boolean = True
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In From row1 As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows Where (From cell As DataGridViewCell In row1.Cells Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value)).Any(Function(cell) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Trim(cell.Value.ToString())))
        isEmpty = False
    Next
    Return isEmpty
End Function
```